# Alternative methods of taking key press input

Tags: batch-file, input, record, keypress

working on a simple batch program where the user is displayed the contents of a text file and can return a new string to the end of the file. My problem is since one batch file is showing the contents and one is taking the input, when a user starts to input something they can not see what they are typing since the contents of the file override it.

#### input.bat

```
@echo off
set target=log.txt
if not exist "%target%" Copy con "%target%"
start /b print.bat "%target%"
type con >> %target%

Echo ERROR!
pause
Exit /b
```

#### print.bat

```
@echo off
if "%~1" equ "" (
cls
Echo ERROR print[0]: No parameter
pause
Exit /b
)
:loop
if not exist "%~1" (
Echo ERROR print[1]: Cannot find targetted file!
pause
Exit /b
)
cls
type "%~1"
sleep -m 50
goto loop
```

Now I know a batch file can take input using either:

- `set /p`
- `choice`
- `type con`

And in the above case I use `type con`, and redirect it to output.txt. However I need the user to be able to see what they are typing, which is very difficult with the contiuous stream of output to the console.

Of course I cam up with the idea of out outputting to the console what the user has typed which is ofcourse possible if I use the `choice` command and record every key press. However there are two problems with this. Firstly, this will prevent me from recording puntuation or otehr speacial characters and secondly it wil not allow the user to "Return" to append the message or to use the backspace key.

This is why I wanted to know if there is any other way of recording a keyboard input in batch, hopefully one which could solve my problem.

For one I know the `pause` and `xcopy /w` command can take one key press **Including `<Enter>` and `<Backspace>`**.

Is there anyway of redirecting this key press to a variable or text file? Is there another method of doing this. If so, please tell me. Now I could easily do this in C#, but I want to finish this project entirely in batch.

Thanks again, Mona.

Comment: @DavidCandy I know, but I have the requirement for calling it from other batch files. Right now I need to deal with each file individually for ease of access. Mona

Comment: You can use a line of VBS to get input in a editable popup window.

Comment: @all I want it to be in the same CMD window